# Running groovy script at the end of Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to run a groovy Post-Build script to do some clean up so I have arranged the following script:

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = '/usr/bin/docker stop mysql'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
```

Although the command '/usr/bin/docker stop mysql' works if I log on the machine, when the groovy script is executed, the following error is raised:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods.execute(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:533)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$894.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:104)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
```

Do you know why the groovy engine fails to find the 'docker' command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Groovy Postbuild](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild) plugin actually runs on the *master*, not on the build node. The documentation states:

> This plugin executes a groovy script in the Jenkins JVM

which is presumably meant to convey "and not in an agent JVM". (Fun side note: If you use `println` in the Groovy script, it prints out to the Jenkins master log, not to the job's console log)

The [Post build task](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task) plugin *does* run on the build node (and you don't need to wrap your shell command in a groovy script). The task requires a condition: to "always run" your script just leave the **Log text** blank.

You might also consider taking a look at the [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/), which lets you bake in try/catch type logic and maintain your pipeline "as code" using a `Jenkinsfile`.